# 302 response when accessing Magento installation

Tags: apache, magento, virtualhost

I've installed Magento and it works fine. However, there is a small issue with accessing the site: when I browse to magento.ourdomain.com I get redirected to serverhostname.ourdomain.com/magento. I would not have expected the redirection to happen and would like to 'stay' on the same domain, i.e. magento.ourdomain.com.

The virtual host config looks like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/magento
    ServerName magento.local
    ServerAlias magento.ourdomain.com
 <Directory /var/www/magento>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm unclear as to why that redirection happens and I don't know whether this is a Magento- or an Apache config issue?

Any ideas or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out with the help of this post: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/192339/#t237666

It seems to have been an issue with directory permissions when I first setup the Magento installation. The following solved this issue:

- delete the /tmp/magento folder: rm -rf /tmp/magento
- delete contents of the /var/www/magento/var/cache and /var/www/magento/var/session directories

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Cheers

Comment: OMG /tmp/magento folder, such a bad trick to go hide something in there.. Thanks a lot for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Delete index.html /var/www solved my problem.